# Does stock Nexus 4 natively rotate to reverse portrait?

Tags: android, rotation, screen-orientation, nexus-4

Not sure if this is the right stack exchange for this question, but seeing how I'm testing an app that I'm developing I thought it would be fitting I ask here. Simple question, does Nexus 4 stock support reverse portrait rotation changes? I can't seem to get anything to rotate to reverse portrait on my Nexus 4 device, nor can I find any info on the web about this. All other orientations work. Does anyone have some official wording, or can at least share a similar experience?

Thanks!

Comment: `if this is the right stack exchange`. This is not stackexchange.

Comment: If I understand correctly, stack overflow is a stack exchange community.